# How to check if firewall is blocking outbound connection to an FTP

Tags: windows-10, firewall, ftp

I am trying to troubleshoot connection to a static FTP site. The connection keeps timing out, and nmap suspects the host is down (it is not). How do I check and confirm whether or not it is firewall settings blocking the outbound connection?

Comment: Disable the firewall and test.

Comment: @Moab If only it were so simple. I do not have access to disabling the firewall.

Comment: You use passive mode to get through a firewall. In standard FTP both ends are servers and clients. You cannot be a server. Hence passive FTP where the server is a server only and you are a client only.

Comment: @user-2147482428 You might explain why and add this information to your question

Comment: PS Windows FTP command line doesn't do passive mode. However Internet Explorer does. Alt + T, O, Advanced tab and it's halfway down towards the end of Browsing Options.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are running Windows I would go to https://canyouseeme.org/ on the ftp server and verify that the server is listening on the server side. On the client side (once again assuming you are running Windows) I would disable the Windows Firewall. You should also check your virus software. On occasion it will have a built-in firewall too.